# Formalizing time and space complexity requirements

Tags: coq, agda, idris

`∀ a b ∈ ℕ, b ≠ 0 → ∃ ! q r ∈ ℕ, a = q × b + r ∧ r < b` is a standard example of the use of dependent types. How do I extend this type so that it also expresses time and space complexity requirements?

Comment: Twan var Laarhoven wrote something about time complexity in Agda, you can check it [here](http://twanvl.nl/blog/agda/sorting). As far as I know, those languages do not have any native way of expressing time and/or space complexity, so you'll have to define the required building blocks yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Nils Anders Danielsson uses a monad in Agda to track time complexity: sub-computations which are "relevant" to the complexity being studied are explicitly marked as such by making each of them take "one tick of time". These sub-computations are then combined monadically by tracking the sum number of ticks in the index of the monad type.

The details are described in his paper *[Lightweight Semiformal Time Complexity Analysis for Purely Functional Data Structures](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~nad/publications/danielsson-popl2008.html)*.

Comment: I've also found these two papers using the monad approach in coq: http://www.eecs.northwestern.edu/~robby/pubs/papers/flops2016-mfnff.pdf and http://www.eelis.net/research/quicksort/